# Social Profile Identity Producing 403 Forbidden Error YQL Console

Tags: yahoo, yql

Using web console. This has worked for 3+ years and now it's producing 403 forbidden on every request/every E-mail. Has the service been discontinued?

```
select * 
from social.profile 
where guid in (select guid 
               from yahoo.identity 
               where yid='globaltraveltrips@yahoo.com')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:
Yahoo Identity table - The yahoo.identity table has been EOLed and no longer supported starting from Sept. 11, 2017

Comment: Adding a link to an announcement (if possible) and a short summary is recommended.

Comment: Problem is there are no announcements, or if they are then their well hidden.  In the past 6 months or so, bits of yahoo have been getting shut down left and center, and trying to get any info on what's happening is met with a deafening wall of silence from it's new owners.  I believe that the new owners are slowly dissembling it from the inside out, throwing away anything that doesn't make money for them, and if something stops working, their not going to inform folks about it, well at least not those of us who use the free services anyway.